# Azure storage account authentication

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to develop a "upload file" solution on Azure where I restrict access to certain containers, or even blobs, inside a single storage account.

The typical scenario is that customer 1 uploads data to container 1, and customer 2 uploads data to container 2.

Is there a build in way to restrict access by credentials of some sort to access specific containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is done through Shared Access Signature (SAS) for containers:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/sas-service-create?tabs=dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-stored-access-policy-define-dotnet?tabs=dotnet

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers. Also, since there are several questions (and answers) regarding SAS already in Stack Overflow, you could post a comment under the question, referring the OP to one of these many questions&answers.